# Contingency table on logistic regression in R with missing fitted values

Tags: r, regression

In my R logistic regression in R, I am trying to create a contingency table comparing fitted to observed values (i.e. 0 or 1 actual vs. 0 or 1 fitted value). However, my data has missing values in various rows of various variables, hence the fitted value vector is of a shorter length than the original data set. Here is an example:

```
test <- data.frame(male=c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1), 
                 height=c(58,100,NA,19,20,69,58,24,46,19,97,69))

model <- glm(male~height, family=binomial("logit"),data=test)

check_model <- table(test$male,fitted.values(model)>0.5)
```

> Error in table(test$male, fitted.values(model) > 0.5) : 
>     all arguments must have the same length

Does anyone know of a way to feed in the actual values (test$male) only in rows where the model has a `fitted.value` that is not `NULL`?

Comment: Did you realize that your code implies that you think there is a function named `fitted.values`? Had you simply typed `?fitted` at the console (or perhaps `str(model)`, you would have made more rapid progress.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at `?glm` you will see that it returns the `model.frame`  (by default) as a component  of the `glm` object

This contains the data used to fit the model

Thus you can use

```
table(model.frame(model)$male, fitted(model) > 0.5)
```

or

```
table(model$model$male, fitted(model) > 0.5)
```

To return your required results

```
##      FALSE TRUE
##   0     4    2
##   1     3    2
```

Comment: `glm` does not return "model.frame". It returns a much more complicated object, from which the function `model.frame` is able to extract the original data.

Comment: I have edited the response to be clearer -- it is returned as *part* of the object of class `"glm"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
> table(test$male[complete.cases(test)], fitted(model)>0.5)

    FALSE TRUE
  0     4    2
  1     3    2
```